# Server crashes after a return statement

Tags: go

I have a service written in Go using `net/http` package.

```
http.HandleFunc("/hello", Hello)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

so far so good.
Inside `func Hello`, a code stub is as below:

```
func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    c, err := r.Cookie("token")
    if err != nil {
        if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
            // If the cookie is not set, return an unauthorized status
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            log.WithFields(log.Fields{
                "fnc": "Hello",
            }).Fatal(err)
            return
            //exit status 1 < Server stops here.
        }
        
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "fnc": "Hello",
        }).Fatal(err)
        return
    }
```

Issues is when code flow reaches where no cookie is found in request  `ErrNoCookie`, the program/server exists after the return statement with the console displaying  `exit status 1` and at client side the error is received as  `Error: read ECONNRESET`

However, as a service I expect it keep running and responding to subsequent requests.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call this:

```golang
log.WithFields(log.Fields{
"fnc": "Hello",
}).Fatal(err)
```

right before returning. And `Fatal` actually exits with code 1.
https://godoc.org/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#Fatal

Try removing all calls to `Fatal`.